# Angularjs: ui-tinymce directive not follow the model updates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When you change the contents of a text editor is updated model, but if the model is updated from another input - content in a text editor window does not change.

Here is an example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/BSkm3u8XuKEFMOXmlS6K?p=preview

I guess i should define watcher for this model and update content in editor manually, but i have not idea how to implement this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to watch the `$scope.<otherTextEditorsData>`  assigned to the other text editor and then update the your editor's DOM when your watch fires.

Comment: Not entirely clear how i can update the editor's DOM. Can you show me an examlpe in plunker?

Comment: like so: tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "your text");

Comment: you can also call: tinymce.activeEditor.setContent("<h1>new content!</h1>");